# Book about a human who believes himself to be a robot

Tags: story-identification, books, robots

I'm from Brazil and the book I'm looking for is one that is very dear to my father, because it is the first science fiction book he read and it sparked a long trajectory of reading the genre. He read it in the 70s, or possibly the 80s, and believes it was written by Isaac Asimov, although i don't think it was.

The book tells the story of a robot that lives in a society where all robots are subservient to humans, and the protagonist admires humans' superiority over robots, like it's physical bodies which seem vastly superior, among other things. Eventually the robot ends up being contacted by a secret robot society that is against their domination by humans, and he ends up learning the great plot twist of the book that the robots like him are actually human, and his overlords are robots pretending to be human. I think the protagonist ends up being instrumental to the plan of this society, as some sort of chosen one that can help them end their subjugation.

He also recalls some very specific passages, which may help to identify the story, such as  him describing for example how his overlords (the fake humans) when cut, bled some beautiful transparent liquid, while him and his kind leaked some ugly red oil, which at the time you don't realize but he is actually talking about blood.

In another passage, he describes how the female robots are taken into factories where new robots are assembled, because the protagonist doesn't understand the idea of pregnancy, since it all happens hidden in those factories.

This is the gist of the plot, but I reckon not all of the elements may actually be in the story, because it's been a long time since he read it, and I think he may be mixing up some elements from other works, like I've seen him do before.

Overall, I think the story might not be from Isaac Asimov, because that description of robots seem to go against anything I know from Asimov's robots, perhaps being from some anthology of stories that Asimov edited and so had his name at the covers. Other details may not be accurate either, or with time became incorporated from other stories he read.

Comment: Was this a novel or a short story?

Comment: I believe it was a complete novel, but it may have been a short story in some anthology